# DB field is displaying from different websites (“ vs â€œ)

Tags: html, character-encoding

On one website an entry pulled from the DB is shown as `“Yes”`. On another website it's displayed as `â€œYesâ€`.

Neither seem to be passed through special functions like `utf8_encode`, near as I can tell (altho one of the websites is using Laravel and there's probably a lot of code that lives between the controller and view that I'm not able to fully appreciate).

The only thing I can figure is that the character set for the websites is different but I guess [Google Chrome now auto-detects the charset](https://superuser.com/a/1160292/172193).

I could make it so that when you add entries to the DB (or when you pull them from the DB) `“` gets replaced with '"' but the concern I have with that is that there could be issues with other characters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the MySQL connection charset / collation.

On the server that showed `“Yes”` it was latin1 / latin1_swedish_ci.

On the server that showed `â€œYesâ€` it was utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

I updated it so that both were utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_unicode_ci and then updated the existant fields thusly:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(column_name USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
```